# how to develop fix menu item in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

I am developing laravel application using 5.2. I have used

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

to display my menu items in the application please see some example

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

@include('layouts.partials.alerts')
<h4>Add Sub Task</h4>
  <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('subtasks.form', ['projectId'=> $project->id, 'taskId'=>$task->id])}}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="text" name="task_name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('task_name') ?: '' }}">
                @if ($errors->has('task_name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('task_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create Sub Task</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
        </div>
@stop
```

but unfortunately when I scrolling mouse to the bottom of the web page my menu item scrolling to the up. but I do not need it. I need fix menu (app). how we can do it

**edited**
see my app.blade.php**
https://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/o9ja87zL/

Comment: Its a css issue, please remove the irrelevant tags from here

Comment: please see my app.blede.php file and here https://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/o9ja87zL/

Comment: Make a jsfiddle of your html and css and share the jsfiddle link

Comment: please see this link https://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/btuqpy5r/

Comment: no any idea here........

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not help anybody because it cannot parse the blade syntax (and it certainly has not the PHP variables available). You need to copy plain HTML / CSS / JS in your Fiddle (basically the source code from the browser when you open the page)

Comment: @Lilan: do what Matthias said